# Weird shifting of boxplot in pandas boxplot combining it with seaborn pointplot - what is going on?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Imagine I have the following dataframes

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

d = {'val': [1, 2,3,4], 'a': [1, 1, 2, 2]}
d2 = {'val': [1, 2], 'a': [1, 2]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d2)
```

This will give me two dataframes that look the following:

```
df =   
    val a
0    1  1
1    2  1
2    3  2
3    4  2
```

and

```
df2 =   
    val a
0    1  1
1    2  2
```

Now I want to create a boxplot based on val in df and the values of a, i.e. fix a value a, i.e. 1; Then I have two different values val: 1 and 2; Then create a box at x=1 based on the values {1,2}; Then move on to a=2: Based on a=2 we have two values val={3,4} so create a box at x=2 based on the values {3,4};

Then I want to simply draw a line based on df2, where a is again my x-axis and val my y-axis; The way I did that is the following

```
ax = df.boxplot(column=['val'], by = ['a'],meanline=True, showmeans=True, showcaps=True,showbox=True)
sns.pointplot(x='a', y='val', data=df2, ax=ax)
```

The problem is that the box for a=1 is shifted at a=2 and the box for a=2 disappeared; I am confused if I have an error in my code or if it is a bug;

[image: One Box is missing, boxes are shifted]

If I just add the boxplot, everything is fine, so if I do:

```
ax = df.boxplot(column=['val'], by = ['a'],meanline=True, showmeans=True, showcaps=True,showbox=True)
```

[image: Correct Boxplot]

The boxes are at the right position but as soon as I add the pointplot, things don't seem to work anymore;

Anyone an idea what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are plotting categories on the x-axis. Pointplot plots the first item at position 0 while boxplot starts at 1, thus the shift. One possibility is to use an twinned axis:

```
ax = df.boxplot(column=['val'], by = ['a'])
ax2 = ax.twiny()
sns.pointplot(x='a', y='val', data=df2, ax=ax2)
ax2.xaxis.set_visible(False)
```

[image: pointplot + boxplot]

Comment: Awesome - but could you explain to me a little bit why this works? In my case, I use the original axis ax, in your case I make a copy of the axis and use the copy; I feel like the result should rather be the same...

Comment: the two axes are displayed with a different xlim, check `ax.get_xlim()` vs `ax2.get_xlim()` ;)